# "onRadioButtonClicked" method not working for radio button implemented by "onCreate" method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

I tried to populate RadioGroup's RadioButtons on "onCreateMethod" rather than using XML because my purpose is to get it from some sort of database or other business objects model that works with randomicity. RadioButtons are fine, but nothing happens when I click them otherwise when I created in XML activity file, not a log message neither a test toast. By the way, as I said, I need to create the buttons by code, thanks, is my first steps in Android.

**My Activity XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/quiz"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**My Code:**

```
public class ListaAlunosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_alunos);

        LinearLayout questoesQuiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.quiz);
        // Log.d(TAG,"Populate List View; Displaying Data in the List View");

        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3"));
        RadioGroup listaDeQuestoes = new RadioGroup(this);
        listaDeQuestoes.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams lp;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
            RadioButton botao = new RadioButton(this);
            botao.setText(dataList.get(i));
            lp = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            listaDeQuestoes.addView(botao, lp);
        }
        questoesQuiz.addView(listaDeQuestoes);
    }


    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


        final String TAG = "MyActivity";


        Log.v("On clicked working", "clicado");

        int id = view.getId();


        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "toast working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast2.show();
  }
}
```

*Buttons are okay!*

[image: Buttons are okay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `onClick` for finding selected radio button is not the best solution but because you want to use `onClick` i will show you how to do it with minimum changes to your code. make these three changes to your code:

```
public class ListaAlunosActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements View.OnClickListener {// <------ 1. implement OnClickListener

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_alunos);

        LinearLayout questoesQuiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.quiz);
        // Log.d(TAG,"Populate List View; Displaying Data in the List View");

        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3"));
        RadioGroup listaDeQuestoes = new RadioGroup(this);
        listaDeQuestoes.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams lp;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
            RadioButton botao = new RadioButton(this);
            botao.setOnClickListener(this);//  <---------- 2.add this line
            botao.setText(dataList.get(i));
            lp = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            listaDeQuestoes.addView(botao, lp);
        }
        questoesQuiz.addView(listaDeQuestoes);
    }
@Override
public abstract void onClick (View v){ //<-------- 3. override onClick
   boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();


        final String TAG = "MyActivity";


        Log.v("On clicked working", "clicado");

        int id = v.getId();// your radio buttons have no id thus use title instead of id:
        String title = ((RadioButton) v).getText();


        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "toast working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast2.show();
}
```

Comment: You are probably right about those three things. But I believe the OP will also have an issue with your code using a general `onClick` method. The user could tap anywhere on the `Activity` and trigger the `onClick` Method. In which case the `View` "v" being returned will not necessarily be a `RadioButton`. Beside this  code `((RadioButton) view).isChecked();`  can not work

Comment: @Barns I do not set `this` Activity as a listener for the root layout or any other views i just set `this` Activity as a listener for Radio Buttons so clicking anywhere other than radio buttons will not trigger `onClick` of this listener and `view` argument of `onClick` always is `RadioButton`.

Comment: Your point about the `onClick()` only pointing to the `RadioButton` I concede. But, I stand by my statement that `((RadioButton) view).isChecked();` can not work... "view" is not defined! "v" is defined, but not "view".

Comment: @Barns as i said i have copy paste the question and only add three changes. this v or view is very subtle and simply is showing in ide as syntax error

Comment: @Barns there may be bigger errors in code but i have concentrated on main problem

Answer (score 2):

If you look keenly, your onRadioButtonClicked is just a method that is never called. Now what you have to do is make the Activity implement RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener. And in onCheckedChanged method, do the Toast and it will work. Here is the code.

```
public class ListaAlunosActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_alnus);

    LinearLayout questoesQuiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.quiz);
    // Log.d(TAG,"Populate List View; Displaying Data in the List View");

    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3"));
    RadioGroup listaDeQuestoes = new RadioGroup(this);
    listaDeQuestoes.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    RadioGroup.LayoutParams lp;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        RadioButton botao = new RadioButton(this);
        botao.setId(i);
        botao.setText(dataList.get(i));
        lp = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        listaDeQuestoes.addView(botao, lp);
    }
    questoesQuiz.addView(listaDeQuestoes);

    listaDeQuestoes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "toast working for id "+ checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast2.show();

}
```

}

I did this and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure what your code is meant to do, but I would use a setOnCheckedChangeListener rather than onClick.

Something like this

```
    listaDeQuestoes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            final String TAG = "MyActivity"; // not used?

            Log.v("On clicked working", "clicado");

            // Note checkedId is +1 when accessing the arraylist so needs to be decremented to get a list item
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(ListaAlunosActivity.this, "toast working clicked (" + checkedId + ") [" + dataList.get(checkedId - 1) + "]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast2.show();
        }
    });
```

The Toast is working and I showed how you can determine which button was clicked and how to access your data array with it, if desired.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for this, as BAHMAN points out, is that you haven't set any listener.  HOWEVER.  Setting a listener on the buttons themselves is not a very good idea.  It is better to set it on the radio group. And it's better to have your layout elements in your layout file.  This makes them easier to modify and understand.

Another thing that is personal preference: I prefer implementing the listener as an anonymous class where it is set. The solutions where the class implements the listener make it harder to read for large classes where it can be annoying to go looking for listeners.  I might make an exception if the listener is very complex or if it something that might be used more than once.

I also cleaned up the code a bit.  Comments added where I did

Anyway, here's how I would write this code:

**Main Activity Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/quiz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity Code:**

```java
public class ListaAlunosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // I put your tag at the top of the class so it's more useful
    public static final String TAG = "ListaAlunosActivity"; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_alunos);

        // You didn't really need an arraylist here for this static content.
        // I just made it an array
        String[] dataList = {"sup1", "sup2", "sup3"}; 

        // Get this from your layout instead of adding it manually.
        // It's a cleaner way to set up the layout that makes the
        // code more maintainable
        RadioGroup listaDeQuestoes = findViewById(R.id.radio_button_list);

        // I changed this to a for each loop because it's a little cleaner
        for (String name : dataList){
            RadioButton botao = new RadioButton(this);
            botao.setText(name);
            listaDeQuestoes.addView(botao);
        }

        // This is the code that will react to the new radio button being selected 
        listaDeQuestoes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // Either way we do it, we need to grab the view to get the name
                RadioButton buttonView = group.findViewById(checkedId);

                // You can use this code to get the index if you need it
                int checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(buttonView);

                // And you can use either of these methods to get the name:
                String buttonNameFromView = buttonView.getText().toString();
                String buttonNameFromDataSource = dataList[checkedIndex];

                String output = "Button with Id: " + checkedId + " and Name: " + buttonNameFromView + " was clicked";

                Log.v(TAG, output);

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ListaAlunosActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                // I set gravity to just center here.  This is the same as center_vertical | center_horizontal.  Personally, I wouldn't set it at all.
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that your solution is better than using `onClick` but you also should change `onCreate` method to add id to each `RadioButton` otherwise you do not know which radio button is checked at `onCheckedChanged`. specially this line of your answer is wrong: `dataList[checkedId]`

Comment: Ah, yes, edited.  Thanks!  He doesn't need to add the IDs explicitly though.  That's more useful for a static list.  The new code will just make sure we get the correct index from the Id.  Or if he had a dictionary or something, he could use that for an Id.  But it seems it would generally be more trouble than it's worth.  

Or he could just check the view's name.